# When an object becomes a property of syncronizationContext?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote this code starting from new winform project.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    object o = new object();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task t = new Task(foo);
        t.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Monitor.Enter(o);

    }

    private void foo()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(o);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        ActionOnUI();

        Console.WriteLine("Thread End");

        Monitor.Exit(o);
    }

    delegate void ActionOnUICrossThread();

    public void ActionOnUI()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new ActionOnUICrossThread(ActionOnUI));
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text += "ab";
        }
    }
}
```

I've used thread.sleep to stop mainThread on Monitor meanwhile the task run.
With breakpoint on  if(InvokeRequired) i can see that InvokeRequired is false, i expected it to be true.

If i remove Thread.Sleep(500); Monitor.Enter(o); on Form1 ctor the InvokeRequired is true, as i expected.

**why is there this different behavior?**

Comment: The behavior of InvokeRequired is a Winforms implementation detail.  It will not become true until the native window is created, only then it it figure out what thread owns that window and only then can the Text assignment cause a threading problem and blow up your program.  So you probably looked at the debugger watch too early.  Using it after the window is closed is similarly troublesome.

Comment: thanks, it's clear

Answer (score 0):

`Task` is not a thread. It merely represents an asynchronous operation. It is up to the task scheduler to put it on a thread or keep it on the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're blocking the form construction by `Monitor.Enter(o);` inside constructor which always loses race conditions to `Monitor.Enter(o);` inside `foo` due to 500 ms sleeping.